# Laravel 5: removing a record from a pivot table with routing issue - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a page where I can add moderators to my forum category (subreddit) and I can see a list of already existing moderators that I have assigned. Both on the same view `create.blade.php`

Next to each moderator, I have a delete link to allow the subreddit's owner to remove moderators as well.

However when clicking on it, give me the following error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Note: in order to access the route to add moderators, I use this `subreddit/{id}/moderators/create`

I understand my routes may be the problem here, these are the routes I'm using

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
Route::resource('subreddit.moderators', 'ModeratorsController');
```

This is the `destroy()` method in ModeratorsController

```
public function destroy(Moderator $moderator, Subreddit $subreddit)
{
   $mod = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $subreddit->id)->where('user_id', '=', $moderator->id)->get();
   $mod->delete();
   return 'done';
}
```

And this is the delete link in the view

```
<a href="{{ action('ModeratorsController@destroy', [$moderator->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a>
```

I don't think the above `action()` will work here because it replaces the `subreddit_id` with the `moderator.id` like this `subreddit/2/moderator` where 2 is the id of the moderator that has replaced 17 which was the id of the subreddit that I was adding moderators to.

I have also tried testing different routes to see if it might work, like `subreddit/{id}/moderators/{modid}/delete` but always got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `resource`, you need to need to send `DELETE HTTP request`.

And you are using [nested resource](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources), you need to send both `$moderator->id` and `$subreddit->id`

In your case, You need to change `a tag` to `form` with `delete method`

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['ModeratorsController@destroy', $moderator->id, $subreddit->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Delete') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And you might need to make some change to destroy function

```
public function destroy($subreddit_id, $moderator_id)
{
   $mod = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', $subreddit_id)
          ->where('user_id', $moderator_id)->first();
   $mod->delete();
   return 'done';
}
```

for more information http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: This gives me an error `ErrorException in helpers.php line 541:
Array to string conversion (View: \subreddit\moderators\create.blade.php)`

Comment: Ok great. I had to put `$subreddit->id` infront of `$moderator->id`and now it seems your delete button is redirecting to the correct route `subreddit/16/moderator/2` 16 is the sub_id and 2 is the mod_id both are correct. But I'm getting this error on submit `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ModeratorsController::destroy() must be an instance of App\Moderator, instance of App\Subreddit given`

Comment: @Halnex, I just updated my answer please take a look. If you get any problem please let me know.

Comment: Your destroy method is giving `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete()` - Why can't I keep injecting the moderator and subreddit models into the destroy() method?

Comment: change `get()` to `first()` in `destroy()`

Comment: That gives `Call to a member function delete() on null`

Comment: I never used `Route model binding` before. I could not suggest for that solution.

Comment: @Halnex. Make sure you has Moderator record with `subreddit_id` and `moderator_id` (user_id) that you want to delete

Comment: I am sure the record exists. I have them listed on the view with the delete button next to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91515/discussion-between-mininoz-and-halnex).